# Download files with NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ftp, nsurl

I am trying to download a list of files from a **ftp** server using:

```
NSURL *ftpUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://xxx:yyy@mzzz.com"];
```

I have to use **ftp**, so please do not recommend an alternative. I want to know how to get the list of files from the root directory and also navigate inside folders (of **ftp** server).

P.S: I do not think external library would be required to accomplish such an easy task, but if I must, any recommendations would be appreciated.

Thank You :)

Comment: It's not 'such an easy task' - networking is a mess. This is not Python (with an effectively infinite standard library so you can just 'import ftp'...)

Answer (score 2):

I've had good success using [Blackracoon](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon). It's a small set of classes you can add to your project that make FTP access easy. You can list files, upload and download files, create directories, etc.

Comment: I cant seem to get the list directory to work since it doesnt return anything.. did u manage to get that to work ?